Wifi Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 not detected in ubuntu 24.04 LTS - HP EliteBook x360 1030 G8
After installing ubuntu 24.04 LTS the Wifi Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 not detected - HP EliteBook x360 1030 G8 (it works correctly on windows 11). (Dual Boot)
My Configuration :
HP EliteBook x360 1030 G8
Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 802.11a/b/g/n/ac (2x2) Wi-Fi
ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I tried to restart the installation by checking the option "Install third-party software for graphics ans Wifi hardware", the Wifi card still not detected.
I tried to install a old Ubuntu version (20.04), the Wifi card still not detected.
I looked for a driver on the Intel website :
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html
I copied the following file (iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode) to folder (/lib/firmware), I restarted but the Wifi card still not detected (Ubunto 24.04 LTS).
I looked for help in forums, youtube, etc. Each time, it's a completely different method, and I don't know if it is suitable for my laptop, the wifi card as well as the version of Linux that I want to install.
Thanks for your help!

This question is similar to: My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I found the solution elsewhere: just disable fast boot on Windows 11 and restart, the wifi appears on ubuntu.
here's how to do disable fast boot on Windows 11 :
https://www.xda-developers.com/disable-fast-startup-in-windows-11/
